How to receive new messages using SkypeEventLoop in SkPy?
The documentation only says that you ccan fetch all messages, not only new messages
https://skpy.t.allofti.me/guides/messages.html
>>> ch = sk.chats["8:joe.4"]
>>> ch.getMsgs()
[SkypeMsg(id='1453283895457', type='Text', time=datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 20, 9, 58, 15, 341000), ...),
 SkypeMsg(id='1452949957379', type='Text', time=datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 16, 13, 12, 37, 109000), ...), ...]

And for the Event and loop, it doesn't involve messages
https://skpy.t.allofti.me/guides/events.html
from getpass import getpass
from skpy import SkypeEventLoop


class MySkype(SkypeEventLoop):

    def onEvent(self, event):
        print(repr(event))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sk = MySkype("fred.2", getpass(), autoAck=True)
    sk.subscribePresence() # Only if you need contact presence events.
    sk.loop()

Is there any way to use the Event to only get new messages (from any user)?

class MySkype(SkypeEventLoop):
def onEvent(self, event):
     # 檢查事件類型
    if isinstance(event, SkypeNewMessageEvent):            
        msg = event.msg  # 獲取訊息對象      
        chat = msg.chat
        chat_topic = chat.topic if hasattr(chat, 'topic') else "No topic"
        print(f"Group: {chat_topic}, Sender: {msg.user.name}, Message: {msg.content}")


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
